# Vue Apollo project - having a separate service is a good way to share states?

Tags: vue-apollo

Noob both in `Vue` and `GraphQL`, I have two pages called `List` page and `Add` page where I show a list or add a new item. If I were in `Angular` project, I would have a `service` that would be responsible to subscribe to a `list` observable so that `Add` page can add a new item to it and `List` page has access to a newly-updated list between page navigation.

Now I am actually working on `nuxt` project that uses `apollo` module to work with `graphql` server, I managed to make each page to work as intended - `list` page makes a query call and shows a list and `Add` page makes a mutation call and get a new list as a response and goes back to the list page where I like to show the new item without making another query call - but wonder if the same approach above to work here. I spent some time to read about `Vuex`, `apollo-cache` and `apollo-subscription` but not sure how to tackle this situation.

Answer (score 1):

There are three Apollo-ey ways of doing this. First, [you can refetch the list query](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#options), which should now include your new item:

```
this.$apollo.mutate({
  mutation: MY_LIST_CREATE_MUTATION,
  variables: {
    name: this.name
  },
  refetchQueries: [
    {
      query: MY_LISTS_QUERY
    }
  ],
  awaitRefetchQueries: true
})
```

Or, you can [update the cache directly based on the results of your mutation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/features/cache-updates/#update):

```
this.$apollo.mutate({
  mutation: MY_LIST_CREATE_MUTATION,
  variables: {
    name: this.name
  },
  update: (store, { data: { listCreate } }) => {
    const data = store.readQuery({ query: Lists });
    data.lists = [ ...lists, listCreate];
    store.writeQuery({ query: Lists, data });
  }
})
```

Or a final way is you can simply tell your Lists page to **always refetch** whenever you browse to that page [using the `fetchPolicy` option](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#optionsfetchpolicy) so it'll always have fresh data:

```
apollo: {
  lists: {
    query: MY_LISTS_QUERY,
    fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
  }
}
```

Personally, I always opt for the final choice. When my app gets more complicated, what if there are **multiple** pages where I'm loading lists. Say there's a main index, but also each user has a specific list of their created lists, or whatever. Then you need to go back and update your `LIST_CREATE_MUTATION` to account for all these new queries.

**Note**: The docs I've linked to above are a mix of React and Angular Apollo documentation. I've found that the Vue Apollo docs don't always do a good job of explaining options like `fetchPolicy` or `refetchQueries` as well as the docs from other Apollo frameworks. In general, I've found that the *options* are interchangeable between frameworks.